# Why is org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar required failed ant build

Tags: jenkins, netbeans, ant

When doing an ant build (thought jenkins) for a test project, I get the below error.  As this test project will be deployed in tomcat why does the build require a netbeans specific module
Obviously I can add the jar file to a path in jenkins and then continue the build, but want to know why it needs a netbeans specific jar?
Is it because the project setup in Netbeans is wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Tony

======Error below here =========

var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DeployTest2/nbproject/build-impl.xml:797: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.

This property must point to 
org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part
of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at

/java/ant/extra folder.
Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library
exists or setup the property manually. For example like this:

ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar